# validate my understanding about DB Locks and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, transactions

I have observed following error logs in one of log files

```
2012-01-31 10:52:46,424 IST WARN           "SQL Error: 2049, SQLState: 42000"
2012-01-31 10:52:46,424 IST ERROR          "ORA-02049: timeout: distributed ransaction waiting for lock"
2012-01-31 10:52:46,440 IST ERROR          "Could not synchronize database state with session"
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92) at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
```

I have class starting a Transaction in which it gets a table LOCK, in the same block of code, as per requirement, we need to start a new transaction which is about to acquire the LOCK on same table it seems. In that case is there a possibility of deadlock and which will be break/resolved by this `Transaction Timeout` exception.

Inner transaction code here:

```
private void createXYZ(final Object tabPortletObject){

        try {
            //get the template
            TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = getTransactionTemplate();
            //create a new transaction template with propagation behavior as requires new
            TransactionTemplate newTransactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate();
            newTransactionTemplate.setTransactionManager(transactionTemplate.getTransactionManager());
            newTransactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
            //start a new transaction and set the status in that new transaction
            newTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                    getHibernateTemplate().save(tabPortletObject);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Exception occured while creating [Tab/Portlet] :" + tabPortletObject);
        }
    }
```

And I have outer transaction which will be started in servlet filter.

My assumption is as inner transaction is waiting for the LOCK acquired by Outer transaction and that outer transaction is waiting to complete executing that block of code to commit the transaction, in which case that LOCK won't be released, leading to a deadlock. Ultimately that inner transaction getting timed out exception to break that deadlock.

Is my statement valid?

This can be resolved if I start a new/inner Transaction in different thread?

Hope you understand it as I am not good at explaining it!

Comment: a "distributed ransaction " - with pitchforks and flaming torches?  ;)

Comment: I can't work out why you need 2 transactions in that snippet.

Comment: I don't know the intention of the another developer in creating a new transaction here. And he is not available now :). And I din't understand your first comment on top what does it mean?

Comment: Locking a table in oracle is generally a very flawed design. why does the table need to be locked. I assume you do not understand the consistent read mechanism.

Comment: @Pokuri, Match is commenting on the log, which seems to be missing a "t".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "This can be resolved if I start a new/inner Transaction in different thread?"

- No.

If this is true:

> I have class starting a Transaction in which it gets a table LOCK, in
>   the same block of code, as per requirement, we need to start a new
>   transaction which is about to acquire the LOCK on same table it seems

then you appear to have a fundemental design flaw.

You either need to hold a less restrictive transaction isolation level, or redesign your logic (or poosibly both).